# Nested For_each or count with dynamic for aws_security_group_rule in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have the requirement to create security group rule with below requirement.

```
Port 22 should have CIDR as [1,2,3]
Port 443 & 80 each should have CIDR as [4,5]
ingress_ports_tcp = [[22], [443,80]]
ingress_cidr_tcp = [[1,2,3], [4,5]]

I am trying below code

  resource "aws_security_group_rule" "tcp1" {
    type               = "ingress"
    count              = (length(var.ingress_cidr_tcp) == length(var.ingress_ports_tcp)) && ( var.ingress_cidr_tcp != "" || var.ingress_ports_tcp != "" ) ? length(var.ingress_ports_tcp) : 0
     dynamic "sg" {  
      for_each = toset(var.ingress_ports_tcp[count.index])
      content {
       from_port = each.value
       to_port = each.value 
       cidr_blocks = var.ingress_cidr_tcp[count.index]
     }
    }    
    security_group_id  = aws_security_group.default-sg[0].id
  }
```

**Error:**

```
Error:Missing required argument on security-group.tf line 16, in resource \"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp1\"resource \"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp1\" The argument \"from_port\" is required, but no definition was found.Error: Missing required argument\  on security-group.tf line 16, in resource \"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp1\"resource \"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp1\" The argument \"to_port\" is required, but no definition was found.Error: Unsupported block type  in resource \"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp1\":\n  19: dynamic \"sg\" Blocks of type \"sg\" are not expected here.
```

Please help.

Comment: What are all these variables; `var.ingress_cidr_tcp) == length(var.ingress_ports_tcp)) && ( var.ingress_cidr_tcp != "" || var.ingress_ports_tcp != "" ) ? length(var.ingress_ports_tcp`? None of them is defined nor their values shown.

Comment: modified the query accordingly.  Please check.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this using a dynamic block
Port 22 should have CIDR as [1,2,3]
Port 443 & 80 each should have CIDR as [4,5]

Comment: Its not possible. `aws_security_group_rule` does not have any dynamic blocks.

Comment: ok, how can we achieve it then? please give some idea.

Comment: Sadly your code does not make sense. For example, why would you use `split` on a list? Its not a string, so what do you want to split?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236044/discussion-between-maya-ray-and-marcin).

Comment: Sorry, couldn't chat. How did it go? Did my answer help?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. What does ```]...) ``` do in this?

Comment: @Glad to hear it work. It will convert `merge([1,2,3]...)` into `merge(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **no such block** as `sg` in `aws_security_group_rule`. Thus, you can't use `dynamic`.

Your issue  could be solved as follows:

```
variable "ingress_ports_tcp" {
    default = [[22], [443,80]]
}

# example with some CIDRs
variable "ingress_cidr_tcp" {
    default = [["172.31.32.0/20", "172.31.64.0/20", "172.31.96.0/20"], 
               ["172.31.128.0/20", "172.31.160.0/20"]]
}


locals {
    my_rules = merge([
            for idx_port, ports in var.ingress_ports_tcp:
                   { for port in ports:
                          "${idx_port}-${port}" => {
                              "port" = port
                              "cidrs" = var.ingress_cidr_tcp[idx_port]
                      }
                   }  
        ]...)
}
```

gives:

```
{
  "0-22" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.32.0/20",
      "172.31.64.0/20",
      "172.31.96.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 22
  }
  "1-443" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.128.0/20",
      "172.31.160.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 443
  }
  "1-80" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.128.0/20",
      "172.31.160.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 80
  }
}
```

then:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "tcp1" {
  
   for_each           = local.my_rules  

   from_port = each.value.port
   to_port = each.value.port
   cidr_blocks = each.value.cidrs

   protocol = "tcp"
   type               = "ingress"    
   security_group_id  = "sg-005923c14af064eec"
}
```