# Security Group using terraform with nested for loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I took reference from the below link and made someone modifications in the input cidr block

[Nested For_each or count with dynamic for aws_security_group_rule in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68802002/nested-for-each-or-count-with-dynamic-for-aws-security-group-rule-in-terraform?noredirect=1#comment121593046_68802002)

Port 22 should have CIDR as ["10.0.0.1/24"]
Port 443 & 80 each should have CIDR as ["172.31.96.0/20","sg-09eadd831567d7dsb","172.31.160.0/20"]

```
ingress_ports_tcp = [[22], [443,80]]
ingress_cidr_tcp = [["172.31.32.0/20"],["172.31.96.0/20","sg-09eadd831567d7dsb","172.31.160.0/20"]]
```

Changes made:
I added security group id as well in the ingress_cidr_tcp variable

```
 locals {
        my_rules = merge([
                for idx_port, ports in var.ingress_ports_tcp:
                       { for port in ports:
                            { for idx_cidr, cidrs in var.ingress_cidr_tcp[idx_port]:
                                    "${idx_port}-${port}-${idx_cidr}" => {
                                    "port" = port
                                    "cidrs" = length(regexall("[0-9].+\\..*",cidrs[idx_cidr])) > 0 ? cidrs[idx_cidr] : null
                                    "security_group_id" = length(regexall("sg-.*",cidrs[idx_cidr])) > 0 ? cidrs[idx_cidr] : null
                            }
                          }
                       }  
            ]...)
    }
```

I want the output like bellow

```
{
  "0-22-0" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.32.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 22
  }
  "1-443-0" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.96.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 443
  }
  "1-443-1" = {
    "security_group_id" = [
      "sg-09eadd831567d7dsb",
    ]
    "port" = 443
  }
  "1-443-2" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.160.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 443
  }
  "1-80-0" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.96.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 80
  }
  "1-80-1" = {
    "security_group_id" = [
      "sg-09eadd831567d7dsb",
    ]
    "port" = 80
  }
  "1-80-2" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.160.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 80
  }
```

Error :

```
Invalid 'for' expression\
Key expression is required when building an object.
```

Comment: It worked fine :) . But can you explain why it was not working in my code , what went wrong logic or syntax.

Comment: After your `for port in ports:` you need something with the key, e.g. `mykey => {your map}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is rather complex input data, so maybe it would be good idea to re-consider simplifying  it. But anyway, you can achieve your outcome as follows. I split it first into `my_rules_cidrs` and `my_rules_sgs`, and then merge them into final `my_rules`:

```
variable "ingress_ports_tcp" {
    default = [[22], [443,80]]
}    

variable "ingress_cidr_tcp" {
    default = [["172.31.32.0/20"], 
               ["172.31.128.0/20", "sg-09eadd831567d7dsb", "172.31.160.0/20"]]
}

locals {

    my_rules_cidrs = merge(flatten([
    for idx_port, ports in var.ingress_ports_tcp:
        [ for port in ports:
            { for idx_cidr, cidr in var.ingress_cidr_tcp[idx_port]:
              "${idx_port}-${port}-${idx_cidr}" => {
                  "port" = port
                  "cidrs" = [cidr]
             } if length(regexall("[0-9].+\\..*",cidr)) > 0
          }
       ]  
    ])...)
    
    my_rules_sgs = merge(flatten([
    for idx_port, ports in var.ingress_ports_tcp:
        [ for port in ports:
            { for idx_cidr, cidr in var.ingress_cidr_tcp[idx_port]:
              "${idx_port}-${port}-${idx_cidr}" => {
                  "port" = port
                  "security_group_id" = [cidr]
             } if length(regexall("sg-.*",cidr)) > 0
          }
       ]  
    ])...)    
    
    my_rules = merge(local.my_rules_cidrs, local.my_rules_sgs)
}
```

Results in:

```
my_rules = {
  "0-22-0" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.32.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 22
  }
  "1-443-0" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.128.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 443
  }
  "1-443-1" = {
    "port" = 443
    "security_group_id" = [
      "sg-09eadd831567d7dsb",
    ]
  }
  "1-443-2" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.160.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 443
  }
  "1-80-0" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.128.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 80
  }
  "1-80-1" = {
    "port" = 80
    "security_group_id" = [
      "sg-09eadd831567d7dsb",
    ]
  }
  "1-80-2" = {
    "cidrs" = [
      "172.31.160.0/20",
    ]
    "port" = 80
  }
}
```