# conflicting issue for aws_security_group_rule attributes cidr_blocks and source_security_group_id

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

Below is the locals `sg_rules` output I am getting check the value for `cidr_blocks` and `security_group_id` variables. At a time either of the values will be

```
"security_group_id" = tostring(null)
```

or

```
"cidr blocks" = tolist([])
```

Locals Outputs :

```
sg_rules = {
    "testsg_1-ingress-1521-tcp-10.80.0.10/32" => {
    "cidr blocks" = tolist(["10.80.0.10/32",]) 
    "description" = "1521 tcp ingress" 
    "from_port" = 1521 
    "protocol" = "tcp" 
    "security_group_id" = tostring(null) 
    "sg_name" = "testsg_1"
    "to_port" = 1521 
    "type" = "ingress" 
  },
    "testsg_2-ingress-1524-tcp-sg-23423439" => {
    "cidr blocks" = tolist([]) 
    "description" = "1524 tcp ingress" 
    "from_port" = 1524 
    "protocol" = "tcp" 
    "security_group_id" = "sg-23423439"
    "sg_name" = "testsg_2"
    "to_port" = 1524 
    "type" = "ingress" 
  }
}
```

using the above local in the `aws_security_group_rule` resource like below getting conflicting error, that both `cidr_blocks` and `source_security_group_id` should not exist at the same time.

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "tcp_cidr_blocks" {
  for_each  = { for key, sg_rule in local.sg_rules : key => sg_rule }
  type      = each.value.type
  from_port = each.value.from_port
  to_port   = each.value.to_port
  cidr_blocks              = each.value.cidr_blocks
  source_security_group_id = each.value.security_group_id
  protocol                 = each.value.protocol
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.security_groups.id
}
```

what I am expecting as either of inputs are null, at a time, so it shouldn't conflict and use either `cidr_blocks` or `source_security_group_id` at a time.

Error:

```
Error: Conflicting configuration arguments\n\n with 
module.sg.aws_security_group_ru1e.tcp_cidr_blocks[\"testsg_2-ingress-1524-tcp-sg-23423439\"],\n on sg/main.tf line 30, in resource 
\"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp_cidr_blocks\" : \n 30: 
source_security_group_id 
= each.value.security_group_id\n\n\"security_group_id\": 
conflicts with cidr_blocks\n",
```

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the current code. Any errors?

Comment: Why not just omit the arguments you know you are not going to use? Additionally, you could maybe use `try` or ternary operator.

Comment: @Marko E. They are in use , I have just omitted them in the code as the error was only in the limited section of the code.

Comment: @Marko E , I have updated the code with all the arguments as well

Comment: @MarkoE 
***with `try` operator***
`Error: Null condition\n\n  on sg/main.tf line 28, in resource \"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp_cidr_blocks\":\n  28:   source_security_group_id = try(each.value.security_group_id) ? each.value.security_group_id : null\n    ├────────────────\n    │ each.value.security_group_id is null\n\nThe condition value is null. Conditions must either be true or false.\n",`

Comment: ***with `can` operator***
`Error: Null condition\n\n  on sg/main.tf line 28, in resource \"aws_security_group_rule\" \"tcp_cidr_blocks\":\n  28:   source_security_group_id = try(each.value.security_group_id) ? each.value.security_group_id : null\n    ├────────────────\n    │ each.value.security_group_id is null\n\nThe condition value is null. Conditions must either be true or false.\n",`

Comment: @AbhishekSolanki I think I found a way to make it work, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second object in your example has:

- `"cidr blocks" = tolist([])`
- `"security_group_id" = "sg-23423439"`

An empty list is not null, so for this object both of the arguments are set at once.

If you set the CIDR blocks attribute to `tolist(null)` instead then you will have a null value for that argument, which may allow this validation rule to pass.

This validation rule is implemented by the `hashicorp/aws` provider in its `aws_security_group_rule` implementation and so exactly how it will interpret these cases is decided by how the logic in the provider is written -- the provider could potentially choose to treat an empty list the same as unset -- but a null value for a resource argument is always exactly equivalent to leaving it unset and so making sure at least one of them is really null is the most robust way to configure this, which should work regardless of how the provider plugin is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with the current code, one being the `=>` which is not a valid syntax in Terraform:

[image]

The second is explicitly casting to types, e.g., `tolist(["10.80.0.10/32",])` and `tostring(null)`. If the local variable `sg_rules` is fixed to look like this:

```
sg_rules = {
    "testsg_1-ingress-1521-tcp-10.80.0.10/32" = {
      "cidr_blocks"       = ["10.80.0.10/32", ] # <---- list instead of type casting
      "description"       = "1521 tcp ingress"
      "from_port"         = 1521
      "protocol"          = "tcp"
      "security_group_id" = "" # <---- empty string instead of type casting
      "sg_name"           = "testsg_1"
      "to_port"           = 1521
      "type"              = "ingress"
    },
    "testsg_2-ingress-1524-tcp-sg-23423439" = {
      "cidr_blocks"       = [""] # <---- empty list of strings instead of type casting
      "description"       = "1524 tcp ingress"
      "from_port"         = 1524
      "protocol"          = "tcp"
      "security_group_id" = "sg-23423439"
      "sg_name"           = "testsg_2"
      "to_port"           = 1524
      "type"              = "ingress"
    }
  }
```

Following that change, using the ternary operator on your code will result in `terraform plan` working:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "tcp_cidr_blocks" {
  for_each                 = local.sg_rules
  type                     = each.value.type
  from_port                = each.value.from_port
  to_port                  = each.value.to_port
  cidr_blocks              = each.value.cidr_blocks != [""] ? each.value.cidr_blocks : null
  source_security_group_id = each.value.security_group_id != "" ? each.value.security_group_id : null
  protocol                 = each.value.protocol
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.security_groups.id
}
```

Setting `cidr_blocks` or `source_security_group_id` to `null` will tell terraform to treat it is an absence of the argument which means it will not complain about conflicting arguments.

Comment: ```=>``` is a valid syntax you can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68830880/security-group-using-terraform-with-nested-for-loop ,  but rest of the issues which you pointed out are correct and working with your solution. Thanks :)

Comment: It is not valid for a map, it is valid however when you are creating one using the `for` loop.

Comment: I am creating using the for loop only , here I have just shown the output of the local variable

Comment: Yup, and that output from the screenshot is taken from your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will leave my answer here just as another example of how to work with JSON files (I imported the security group rules first as I was working with existing resources):

```
[
 {
    "description": "Remove me",
    "from_port": 500,
    "to_port": 500,
    "protocol": "udp",
    "source_security_group_id": "",
    "cidr_blocks": ["xxx.xx.xx.xxx/xx"]
 },
 {
    "description": "Remove this rule",
    "from_port": 5000,
    "to_port": 7000,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "source_security_group_id": "sg-xxxx8f180c16xxxx",
    "cidr_blocks": [""]
 }
]

locals {
  ingress_security_groups = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/components/ingress_security_groups.json"))
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress_rule" {
  count                    = length(local.ingress_security_groups)
  type                     = "ingress"
  description              = local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].description
  from_port                = local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].from_port
  to_port                  = local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].to_port
  protocol                 = local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].protocol
  source_security_group_id = local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].source_security_group_id != "" ? local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].source_security_group_id : null
  cidr_blocks              = local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].cidr_blocks != [""] ? local.ingress_security_groups[count.index].cidr_blocks : null
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.this.id
}
```